# Why Codon W doesn't install in my laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Codon W (http://codonW.sourceforge.net) is a software for calculation of codon usage indices.

I sourced it and tried to install in my laptop but it failed as the codonW installer is missing extension for installation.

I have had downloaded a compressed file.

I am using Windows 10, 64bit.

What should be done to incorporate an active extension code?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Exactly, word for word.

Comment: #Provisional failure. Installation of a provision package failed. Please work with the package author to diagnose the problem. Reported error: 0x80070057

Comment: Sounds like the installer may be corrupted. Try looking either for older versions or alternative builds. But given that the project apparently hasn't been maintained since 2005 and the latest version wasn't even built for Windows, I wouldn't get my hopes too high.

Comment: Basically, I am looking at whichever person who has ever worked with codon W through laptop. How did he arrive at installation. On my side, I deleted files and repeated installation  several times unsuccessfully.

Comment: It's 18yo software! Are you trying to install the binaries? From the web page, it's very old software last confirmed to run on XP and only with 32bits.

Comment: Correct! What other means to be used in windows 10?

Comment: You could install Windows XP in Virtual Box and install Codon W on there. https://www.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 1):

No need to install. Download the zip file **Win32CodonW_1_4_2.zip** , unzip, and run **CodonW.exe** from the Win32 folder.

The windows version has no user interface. It emulates a dos terminal. read the Readme.txt file for help

Comment: It brings the same error. May be it was not designed  for x64 bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you gave:

> **Binaries are available for the following operating systems.**

> 4. **Win 32bit (NT/95/98/2000/XP)** (No GUI; runs within a DOS emulation window)

Correct me if wrong, but looks like windows 10 is just not supported by your program.

Comment: Absolutely right.  Probably was not designed for Win 64 bit